# Excel - use sublist delimiter power query without duplicating data

Tags: excel, csv, powerquery

I am unable to transform my CSV in the way that I want. I have looked online, but have been unable to find a resolution to my problem.

I have the following CSV:

```
name;number;list
"name1";1234;"1. item1
2. item2
3. item3
";"name2";4567;"1. item4
2. item5
3. item6
"
```

I want to transform that into the below table:

| name | number | list |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "name1" | 1234 | item1 |
|  |  | item2 |
|  |  | item3 |
| "name2" | 4567 | item4 |
|  |  | item 5 |
|  |  | item 6 |

Except when I use the power query delimiter it gives me a lot of duplicate data, like so:

| name | number | list |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "name1" | 1234 | item1 |
| "name1" | 1234 | item2 |
| "name1" | 1234 | item3 |
| "name2" | 4567 | item4 |
| "name2" | 4567 | item 5 |
| "name2" | 4567 | item 6 |

Comment: Really curious to know why you don't want the duplicate data?  Or do you want `item1, item2, item3` to be in the same cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your source CSV (which is pretty badly formed):

```
name;number;list
"name1";1234;"1. item1
2. item2
3. item3
";"name2";4567;"1. item4
2. item5
3. item6
"
```

Opening in Power Query, with the semicolon delimiter, results in =>
[image]

Read the code comments and check each `Applied Step` for the steps involved in transforming it to your pictured result:

```
let
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\ron\Desktop\New Text Document.csv"),
        [Delimiter=";", Columns=3, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"name", type text}, {"number", Int64.Type}, {"list", type text}}),
    
    #"Removed Blank Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", 
        each not List.IsEmpty(List.RemoveMatchingItems(Record.FieldValues(_), {"", null}))),

//Replace blanks in list with "name", then delete "name"
    #"Replace Blank list items" = Table.ReplaceValue(
        #"Removed Blank Rows",
        each [list],
        each [name],
        (x,y,z)=> if x = "" or x = null then z else x,
        {"list"}),

//Remove items and trim "name" column
    #"Remove list items" = Table.ReplaceValue(
        #"Replace Blank list items",
        each [name],
        each [list],
        (x,y,z)=> if y = z then null else x,
        {"name"}),

    #"Quote name" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Remove list items",{
        {"name", each """" & Text.Trim(_,{";",""""}) & """", type text}}),

    #"Remove Chars from list" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Quote name",{
        {"list", each Text.TrimStart(_,{"0".."9","."," "}), type text}})
in
    #"Remove Chars from list"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could create a PivotTable and apply some settings to make your input look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/al1lM.png).

With the PivotTable selected, go to the [Design tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJaqi.png).

Turn off [subtotals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TouFF.png) and [row and column totals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDT7u.png), then apply the [Tabular Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1eSK.png):

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm not sure how I'd go about that. I receive the CSV from a source with several data types, and I can do very little to change that. I get some string fields, some integer fields, and a list field. That list field is what I'm trying to split up here. What you're suggesting would require me to turn every item of my CSV into a list object? Which doesn't seem very straightforward, though I appreciate the suggestion. Unfortunately, even if that would work, it's not a change I can make without adding intermediate editing steps which ideally I'd like to avoid.

Comment: I changed my answer since I can only post every 30 minutes... I'm new to this

Comment: Thank you for the edit. Unfortunately it isn't easy to edit new data to the pivot table proper, but it's definitely workable.

Comment: Hi tbeest, if you have a Power Query query to import your CSV files you can load the data from Power Query into a PivotTable like this automatically. Then when your Power Query query picks up any new CSV files and you update the query, the data should go into this PivotTable automatically and you don't need to make a new one or reformat it for example. Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

How about this in powerquery? You can paste into home...advanced editor....  and then get it back into excel with file ... close and load...

```
let Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\Temp\a.csv")),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(Source, {{"Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("#(lf)", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Column1"),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Split Column by Delimiter", "Custom", each try Text.Repeat(";",2-(List.Count(Text.Split([Column1],";"))-1)) & [Column1] otherwise 
    if Text.Start([Column1],1)=";" then Text.AfterDelimiter([Column1],";") else [Column1]),
NewColumns=List.Transform({1 .. List.Max(List.Transform( #"Added Custom"[Custom], each List.Count(Text.Split(_,";"))))}, each "combined_"& Text.From(_)),
split = Table.SplitColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv), NewColumns),
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(split, [PromoteAllScalars=true])
in  #"Promoted Headers"
```

[image]

Right click remove first column if wanted

Right click and fill down name and number columns if wanted

**alternate version that removes numbers from list column**

```
let Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\Temp\a.csv")),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(Source, {{"Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("#(lf)", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Column1"),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Split Column by Delimiter", "Custom", each try Text.Repeat(";",2-(List.Count(Text.Split([Column1],";"))-1)) & [Column1] otherwise 
    if Text.Start([Column1],1)=";" then Text.AfterDelimiter([Column1],";") else [Column1]),
NewColumns=List.Transform({1 .. List.Max(List.Transform( #"Added Custom"[Custom], each List.Count(Text.Split(_,";"))))}, each "combined_"& Text.From(_)),
split = Table.SplitColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv), NewColumns),
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(split, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
#"Remove End" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Promoted Headers",{{"list", each Text.AfterDelimiter(_,". "), type text}})
in  #"Remove End"
```

[image]

the whole thing is hard coded for 3 columns with the 2- part of the code

Comment: Thank you for the extensive suggestion. Could you explain a little more how the 2- part works? As the actual dataset I have goes up to 16 columns

Comment: provide a sample CSV set that goes to more items